# User authentication through Google plus in android app

Tags: java, android, authentication, google-plus

I am working with Android app.
User authentication in app with three way.
First is simple authentication done with query.
Second with Facebook. It also done.

I am working on Google plus authentication. but I am not able find the proper document as provide in facebook app.

Can any one guide me for google plus authentication?

Comment: I don't think Google Plus has its own authentication system, it just uses the Google Account, so you could build a login system using the Google Authentication system and everyone with a Google+ Account could just use that.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to take a look at "**Google Play Services**" in the Android SDK ([released on 09/26](https://plus.google.com/+GooglePlusDevelopers/posts/AHdqSf6G21y)).

> Google Play services is a platform delivered by the Google Play Store
>   that offers integration with Google products, such as Google+ into
>   Android apps. The Google Play services framework consists of a
>   services component that runs on the device and a thin client library
>   that you package with your app.

The following components are included in Google Play services v1 and corresponding client APIs are included in the client library:

- OAuth 2.0 authentication
- Google+ sign-in
- Google +1 button

Here's the link to it on on Googles Developer site:
https://developers.google.com/android/google-play-services/index

Comment: Google Play Services has now been released and is available for download from the SDK Manager!

Answer (score 0):

To add onto what chrkad suggested, there are also the Google+ mobile APIs:
https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/

and for Android, specifically:
https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/

These services will enable you to get the plus.me scope for a given account which you could then use for authentication and user credentials.  Using a conventional OAUTH2 flow, you could do this now, it will be easier once the APIs are released.